# laravel 8 , I have a relationship between 3 tables attribute and value and ad

Tags: pivot-table, laravel-8

ad model

```
public function attvalues()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Attrvalue::class,'attribute_ad')- 
      >withPivot('attribute_id');
}

public function attributes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class,'attribute_ad')->withPivot('attrvalue_id');
}
```

Attribute model

```
public function attvalues()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Attrvalue::class,'attribute_ad')->withPivot('ad_id');
}

public function ads()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Ad::class,'attribute_ad')->withPivot('attrvalue_id');
}
```

Attrvalue model

```
  public function attributes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class,'attribute_ad')->withPivot('ad_id');
}

public function ads()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Ad::class,'attribute_ad')->withPivot('attribute_id');
}
```

In this way, save attribute and value and ad in pivot table

```
if (count($request->input('attribute_id')) > 0) {
        $date2 = array();
        foreach ($request->input('attribute_id') as $key => $value) {
            $adAttribute = array(
                'ad_id' => $ad->id,
                'attribute_id' => (int)$request->attribute_id[$key],
                'attrvalue_id' => (int)$request->attvalue_id[$key],
            );
            
            array_push($date2, $adAttribute);
        }
        $ad->attributes()->attach($date2);
    }
```

Everything is fine and I was saving the (id) in the pivot table. I realized the wrong idea because I will have an attribute that takes multiple values. How do I solve the problem?

return $request;

```
      {
      "attribute_id": [
                "1",
               "2",
                "3"
                     ],
       "attvalue_id": [
           "1",
           "4",
           "7",
           "8"
                    ],
```

but only saved

```
    attrvalue_id  |attribute_id  |ad_id 
     1            |1             |6
     4            |2             |6
     7            |3             |6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved i changed pivot table to

```
    attrvalue_id   |ad_id 
     1             |83
     4             |83
     7             |83
     8             |83
```

and i get attribute form elquent between attribute and attrValue

```
$ad = Ad::with('images','attvalues.attribute')->find($id);
```